# Parallelising light rays from a laser projector using planoconvex lens

Tags: optics, lenses, home-experiment

**Materials:**
26mm Dia x 35.2mm FL, Grade 1, Plano-Convex Lens. PicoP laser picoprojector.

**The problem:**
I've got a question about using a lens to parallelise light rays coming from a laser projector.
The projector is noted to be in focus at any distance from the wall upon which you project, and as far as I've seen this is true. But as with any projector the light coming out of it comes in a cone-shape, meaning that the larger the distance the larger the image.

**The plan:**
I was hoping to use a lens to make the light from this cone come out parallel to the principle axis, and thus yield an image of the same size regardless of the distance.

**My question:**
However the image comes out blurry, and has left me (someone inept at physics) wondering if my thought process is even correct. So I'm here to ask, can this be achieved? Am I on the right track? What would I need to improve this system?